# Как запустить Qt Designer в PyQt5-tools?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyqt5, qt-designer

Установлены: `Python3.6`, `PyQt 5.9`. Хочу использовать `QT Designer`.

Установил `PyQt5-tools 5.9` через `pip`. Там есть файл `designer.exe`.

Во множестве источников говорится, что это файл нужно просто кликнуть и запустится среда `QT Designer`. Но у меня при этом не происходит ничего. Нет сообщений об ошибках и нет никаких действий. Операционная система `Windows 7 32bit`.

Comment: У меня сейчас: 
Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1 ; 
Python: 3.7.3 ; 
Версия PyQt 5.12.1 ; 
Qt Designer version 5.11.2 . 

Набираю в командной строке `designer` - запускается Qt Designer,
точно так, как если просто кликнуть файл designer.exe
 Может вам надо обновить версии?

Comment: Я начинал пробовать с более поздних версий, Python 3.7, PyQt 5.13, но результат бы такой же. Я читаю книгу о PyQt и перешёл на более старые версии, которые использовались авторами книги. Но это не помогло. В интернете я не нашёл ни одного случая описания такой проблемы. У меня не запускается ни кликом ни вызовом из командной строки.

Comment: Выяснил, что это проблема моего компьютера. Designer успешно запускается на другом компьютере с такой же Windows 7. Проблем с запуском других приложений у меня нет, только с этим.